# trying to make a program that only accepts single digit inputs and then displays after it hits the 10th input

Tags: python, loops

```
userInput = []
for i in xrange(1, 10):
    userInput.append(raw_input('Enter the %s number: '))
userInput = ''
while len(userInput) != 1:
    userInput = raw_input(':')
guessInLower = userInput.lower()
print"the numbers you have entered are: ", userInput
```

so I am trying to make a program that takes 10 single digit inputs and then puts them into a single string then after it hits 10 inputs of single digits it then prints out all the single digit inputs I have gotten this far but I can't find a way for it to check to first. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: whats your real output and desire out put ?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is I am having issues figuring out how to set the code up to where it firsts checks to see if the number inputted by the user is a single character input if it isn't it would prompt the user til it got one, then if all is going well it would ask for single character digits until 10 of them are inputted then it will output those 10 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it all inside a single loop and check if the input is a single digit:

```
user_inp = ""
while len(user_inp) < 10:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a digit")
    if len(inp) == 1 and inp.isdigit(): # check length and make sure a digit is entered
        user_inp += inp
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
print("The numbers you have entered are: {}".format(user_inp))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, the following code is what you want:

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/1lW)

#### Code:

```
userInput = ""

for i in xrange(1, 11):
    userInput += (raw_input('Enter the %s number: '))

print"the numbers you have entered are: ", userInput
```

#### Output:

```
Enter the %s number:  1
Enter the %s number:  2
Enter the %s number:  3
Enter the %s number:  4
Enter the %s number:  5
Enter the %s number:  6
Enter the %s number:  7
Enter the %s number:  8
Enter the %s number:  9
Enter the %s number:  0
the numbers you have entered are:  1234567890
```